# Table layout in repeater control

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I am trying to get the Table shown in the image as layout in a repeater control.Since i am newbie to it
Can someplease guide me on this. The section below Customer number is the only thing that should repeat vertially and I want only two repeats (i.e two item details per page ) on each page

Thank You

[image]

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterVersionsForPie" runat="server">

            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table id="VersionsTable">
            </HeaderTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
    <td class="style3">CustomerNumber</td>    
    <td class="style4">Test1:</td>    
    <td class="style5">Test2</td>    
    <td class="style7">Test3:</td>    
    <td class="style8">Test4:</td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>   
   <td class="style9"></td>    
   <td class="style10"></td>    
   <td class="style11"></td>    
   <td class="style12"></td>    
   <td class="style13"></td>
  </tr>    
            </ItemTemplate>

            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I have edited my question to show what i tried so far..Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterVersionsForPie" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="VersionsTable">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">CustomerNumber</td>    
            <td class="style4">Test1:</td>    
            <td class="style5">Test2</td>    
            <td class="style7">Test3:</td>    
            <td class="style8">Test4:</td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>   
            <td class="style9" colspan="5"></td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item Type:</td>
            <td rowspan="3" colspan="4" valign="top">Photo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item Number:</td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date:</td>    
        </tr>   
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here's a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anx1gq6j/)